# how to implement Jquery datatable in android any library?

Tags: android

I have to try to implement jquery Datatable in android. I found some library from Github like evrencoskun TableView and another one is a sortable table view it's not fully customize.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 sample apps of [TableView](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView)  library

These are;

- https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView/tree/master/app
- https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableViewSampleApp

[This](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView#installation) may also help to be able to implement this library to your project.

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a TableView library in Kotlin, here it is: [android-tableview-kotlin](https://github.com/ingenuity-ph/android-tableview-kotlin). It is the Kotlin port of the TableView by evrencoskun.