# How to add the data from an api without Pojo

Tags: android, string, list, api, arraylist

I am getting data from an api which cannot be converted into pojo so am not able to get the data in a normal manner 
Data that i am getting

```
 {"TABLE_DATA":"
{\"data\":[
[\"Tiger Nixon\",\"System 
Architect\",\"Edinburgh\",\"5421\",\"2011/04/25\",\"$320,800\"],
[\"Garrett 
Winters\",\"Accountant\",\"Tokyo\",\"8422\",\"2011/07/25\",\"$170,750\"],
[\"Ashton Cox\",\"Junior Technical 
Author\",\"SanFrancisco\",\"1562\",\"2009/01/12\",\"$86,000\"],
[\"Cedric Kelly\",\"Senior Javascript 
Developer\",\"Edinburgh\",\"6224\",\"2012/03/29\",\"$433,060\"],
[\"Airi 
Satou\",\"Accountant\",\"Tokyo\",\"5407\",\"2008/11/28\",\"$162,700\"],
[\"Brielle Williamson\",\"Integration Specialist\",\"New 
York\",\"4804\",\"2012/12/02\",\"$372,000\"],
[\"Herrod Chandler\",\"Sales Assistant\",\"San 
Francisco\",\"9608\",\"2012/08/06\",\"$137,500\"],
[\"Rhona Davidson\",\"Integration 
Specialist\",\"Tokyo\",\"6200\",\"2010/10/14\",\"$327,900\"],
[\"Colleen Hurst\",\"Javascript Developer\",\"San 
Francisco\",\"2360\",\"2009/09/15\",\"$205,500\"],
[\"Sonya Frost\",\"Software 
Engineer\",\"Edinburgh\",\"1667\",\"2008/12/13\",\"$103,600\"],
[\"Jena Gaines\",\"Office 
Manager\",\"London\",\"3814\",\"2008/12/19\",\"$90,560\"]`
```

there is no pojo available This is my first time working in an API any guide will be helpful. I am receiving the following data using retofit and rxjava2.
Data format is post method .

Answer (score 0):

This is a  jquery format. You may try to use this https://javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/jquery-datatables-and-java-integration.html

Look also this topic [stackoverflow.com/questions/48942253/how-to-implement-jquery-datatable-in-android-any-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942253/how-to-implement-jquery-datatable-in-android-any-library)

The service you get data from may have an opportunity to set data format, you must specify it in your GET query, look in the API documentation.

Comment: I want to add the data in the array list the first link has pojo and the data i am getting there is no pojo the following data format is post method

Answer (score 0):

That looks a lot like a .csv file. CSV files were the old format of Comma Separated Values, built from Tabular data.

Each row is one object and each column is its attribute/field. You can read about CSV files [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

**Approach 1**

Filter out using string manipulation the extra symbols of slashes and quotes. Delimit at the square braces (more info [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/)) and then reading each delimited comma separated value text by any CSV reading library. Here's a tutorial using [Apache Commons CSV library](https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-write-csv-file-apache-commons-csv/) to read CSV files in Java.

**Approach 2**

Instead of using any library, if your response set is small and you don't need as much parsing optimization, write your object class's constructor to take in each row, filter out the useless symbols (using string manipulation) and initialize your object's fields.

**All steps involved**:

1. Clean response and remove unnecessary symbols using string manipulation.
2. Build a POJO class to keep one row of the dataset. Have its constructor to take in the first row of your dataset to initialize its attributes.
3. Build a list format or ArrayList format of your previous class with additional methods to sort, search or call by indices as required.
4. Build a constructor for this list object class to read in your cleaned string response and iterate over it to build Employee objects and adding them to your list.

Comment: Sir i started with the csv files but the data is quite large through csv its is not possible as i can do it by other way but i will end up with just string with all the value I am asking here when i have gone through all the possible way like json array to string and many more way

Comment: If your dataset is too large, are you sure you need to read all that data? A large data set is rarely used with an Android app, as device memory is very limited. What are you using the data for? If you're using it to just display it, then you might want to look into pagination: https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-pagination-tutorial-getting-started-recyclerview/

Comment: even if i try by the csv method i will end up having other symbols and the following output will not be saved in the array list

Comment: That seems more like an issue with your regex filtering. Unless you clean your response, it cannot be read correctly by your methods or even parsing libraries. What is your use case with the dataset, if you can tell, we can see if we solve the issue any other way.

Comment: I have to show the data into the listview or recycler view and a graph which represent the salary of people i can do these things once i get the data into arraylist

Comment: What is the issue you are facing currently? Have you been able to parse and store the response data correctly? I'd suggest you look into https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging and Pagination, to handle lots of data. You'll have to use RecyclerView instead of ListView as it is optimized.

Comment: the data i am receiving from the api is in this format and i am not able to set them in the arraylist as there is no pojo available in the api data i cannot simply add the data once it is received what i am getting is a chunk of value .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189713/discussion-between-md-naseem-ashraf-and-neelay-srivastava).

Comment: the data in the question is the data that i am receiving